# Rabin-Karp algorithm: Why is h=(h*d)%q

Tags: java, string, algorithm, search, rabin-karp

I understand the following in the Rabin-Karp algorithm

h=d^m-1 but I fail to understand why we write

```
for(i=0;i<M-1;i++)
    h=(h*d)%q
```

in the code

Comment: I doubt there's enough data in this question for anyone to provide a useful answer. Can you share the implementation you're referencing?

Comment: (Looks an incomplete snippet from open coded coalesced chaining.)

Comment: This is from the Java coding of the algorithm

Comment: Whatever it comes from, you should reference your sources to let others understand your point and give hints

Answer (score 0):

basically , these lines are initialising default values to your hashmaps , which you are going to change later ,and it also work as a hash function , when you will insert values , for more deep  ,read below paragragh , also vote and follow my profile .
When you were trying to understand concept of hashmaps , everyone teaches you by making some block in series . later , these blocks were initialised some key values but the block were uninitialised before you insert key values . so there may be chances that some blocks were not given any key values . they will contain garbage values , and how can you traverse over them becoz when you need to search something, you need to traverse , so that function is initialising a default value to all blocks . now if you try to run your code without these lines , your code will check for 1st time only . as i know , these code lines are from geeksforgeeks rabinkarp algorithm , try running that code without those line and you wil get checked for 1st value only and not get desired answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To be precise, the loop is not calculating **ℎ=−1**, but **ℎ=(−1) mod** . This is an important detail, because that means whatever the value of  or  is, the result will never exceed .

Also, the code block you presented needs to be preceded with `h=1` to make sense.

With a loop we can avoid large intermediate results, which could risk crossing the range supported by the integer type being used. Typically the size of the string alphabet () is set to 256. Now if the length of the pattern to search () is like 20, then  = 256<sup>20</sup> = 2<sup>160</sup>, a number that does not fit in the typical 32 or 64-bit integer storage. So calculating −1 just like that risks to lead to numeric overflow.

That is why the loop is used. At each iteration the modulo operator is applied, which with normal values of  and  eliminates the risk of overflow. It is also [correct](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2416119/rules-for-modulus-and-multiplication) to apply the modulo operator at each iteration.